# i have to check multiple columns are in range of remaing two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a pandas dataframe like 
dd1=

```
  A    B    C   D   E   F
  10   18   13  11   9   25
  0    32   27  3  18   28
  4     6   3   29  2   23
```

and i want to check columns A to D are between the range of Columns E and F.
I want output like that is if it is in range in result column 0 otherwise that value which is out of range..

dd1=

```
    A   B   C    D   E    F   Result
    10  18   13  11  9   25  0
     0  32   27  3  18   28  [0,32]
     4   6   3   29  2   23  29
```

i tried like these:

```
 dd1=dd1.loc[dd1.iloc[:,0:3].between(dd1['E'],dd6['F'])]
```

Comment: This is unclear... in row `0`, all columns are in the range 9-25, but the output is `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, :4]

m1 = df1.gt(df['E'], axis=0)
m2 = df1.lt(df['F'], axis=0)

df['Result'] = df1.mask(m1 & m2).apply(lambda x: x.dropna().astype(int).tolist(), axis=1)
print (df)
    A   B   C   D   E   F      Result
0  10  18  13  11   9  25          []
1   0  32  27   3  18  28  [0, 32, 3]
2   4   6   3  29   2  23        [29]
```

If need `0` for non matched values:

```
s = df1.mask(m1 & m2).apply(lambda x: x.dropna().astype(int).tolist(), axis=1)
df['Result'] = np.where(s.astype(bool), s, 0)
print (df)
    A   B   C   D   E   F      Result
0  10  18  13  11   9  25           0
1   0  32  27   3  18  28  [0, 32, 3]
2   4   6   3  29   2  23        [29]
```